# Thread (Attempt to use a deleted function

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm following an online tutorial on threading and got the error message "Semantic Issue: Attempt to use a deleted function". Any idea what's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Fctor {
public:
    void operator() (string & msg) {
        cout << "t1 says: " << msg << endl;
        msg = "msg updated";
    }
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    string s = "testing string " ;
    thread t1( (Fctor()), s);

    t1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: The object constructed by Fctor() does not live long enough to be used in a thread.

Comment: @bmargulies No, that is fine. It is a problem with the other parameter, `s`. I guess `std::ref(s)` would work.

Comment: First problem I see is trying to pass an object in to be passed to the functor as an lvalue, but `std::thread` applies lvalue-to-rvalue conversions to the types of the arguments so the call would fail since it won't pass an lvalue. Try wrapping it with `std::reference_wrapper` (`thread t1(Fctor(), std::ref(s))`)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code works with VS2015, MS-Compiler, with these change to the code:

This

```
void operator() (string & msg) {
    cout << "t1 says: " << msg << endl;
    msg = "msg updated";
}
```

to

```
void operator() (std::string& msg) {
    std::cout << "t1 says: " << msg.c_str() << std::endl;
    msg = "msg updated";
}
```

and this

```
string s = "testing string " ;
thread t1( (Fctor()), s);
```

to

```
std::string s = "testing string ";
Fctor f;
std::thread t1(f, s);
```

The two main things I changed was msg.c_str(), because the stream doesn't take string, but const char*.
Second, I turned the RValue Fctor() into the LValue Fctor f and gave f as the parameter, the thread apparently doesn't take RValues.